# How to read local file from a chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, fs

I build a chrome extension project using webpack and I need to read a local bundle file from content script this way:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const content = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, 'inpage.js'),
  'utf8',
);
```

But `fs` is undefined in my build, so the question is How can I successfuly build project with the `fs` in the content script OR how can I include the raw xxx.bundle.js file into my content script to use it as string?
P.S. indefined `fs` is a popular issue, but there is no answer that helped me. But I know it's possible because some extensions can do this.

Comment: Browsers don't have `fs` so you'll need a completely different solution e.g. use a loader plugin like [raw-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) that reads a file *at build time* and outputs it as a string.

Comment: I've tried `raw-loader` but it looks like it doesn't load content as a string. I mean, when I import the file it imports only the file name. It works well when you use it with the src attribute on some html tags, but this is not that I need

Comment: I've tried it again and IT WORKS! Thank you. But I still have a little problem. To make it work I copied a bundle file from the dist folder to src and renamed it to xxx.txt. How can I do it at building? Or maybe there is another workaround?